# Setting combobox values on initialisation and change of other comboboxes

Tags: excel, combobox, excel-2013, userform, vba

(EDIT: To clarify, I'm running Excel 2013, so Microsoft's date picker isn't available.)

I'm trying to code a simple date picker - it'll be tidier when it's done, it's just big for simplicity while I build it - and everything populates as it should:

[image: Date picker form]

```
Me.Combo_Year.List = wsLU.Range("Date_Years").Value
Me.Combo_Month.List = wsLU.Range("Date_Months").Value
Me.Combo_Day.List = wsLU.Range("Date_Days31").Value
```

However, there are two instances where I'd like to set default values for the year, month and day comboboxes. For the times I'm using spin buttons, where a simple `.Value` statement sets them to 12 noon in the `_Initialize`. But neither `.Value` nor `.Text` works for the comboboxes:

```
Me.Combo_Year.Text = Year(Now())  ' Doesn't work
Me.Combo_Month.Text = Month(Now())  ' Doesn't work
Me.Combo_Day.Text = Day(Now())  ' Doesn't work
Me.Spin_Hour.Value = 12  ' Works fine
Me.Spin_Minute.Value = 0  ' Works fine
```

[image: Error on initialising]

Similarly, when I try to set the date to a lower value when a month with fewer days is selected (to avoid returning the 31st of February, for instance), both `.Value` and `.Text` prove unhelpful again:

[image: Debug line after changing month]

Is there any way to reliably set a default value and later change the value of a combobox in code? Am I missing something hugely obvious?

EDIT: For reference, the full code for the relevant parts of the form (`UpdatePreview` just updates the preview date above the OK button) as requested:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Option Explicit

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim wsLU As Worksheet, wbV As Workbook
Set wbV = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsLU = wbV.Worksheets("General Lookups")

Me.Combo_Year.List = wsLU.Range("Date_Years").Value
Me.Combo_Month.List = wsLU.Range("Date_Months").Value
Me.Combo_Day.List = wsLU.Range("Date_Days31").Value
Me.Combo_Minute.AddItem 0
Me.Combo_Minute.AddItem 30

' Tried putting the date numbers via variables instead of direct, with various data types
Dim TestYear As String, TestMonth As String, TestDay As String
TestYear = Year(Now())
TestMonth = Month(Now())
TestDay = Day(Now())
Lab_T_Year.Caption = TestYear
Lab_T_Month.Caption = TestMonth
Lab_T_Day.Caption = TestDay
'Me.Combo_Year.Text = TestYear    ' If these lines are commented out the form will load, though without the comboboxes prepopulated
'Me.Combo_Month.Text = TestMonth  ' If these lines are commented out the form will load, though without the comboboxes prepopulated
'Me.Combo_Day.Text = TestDay      ' If these lines are commented out the form will load, though without the comboboxes prepopulated

' Original code; tried this both with and without various Format types.
'Me.Combo_Year.Value = Format(Year(Now()), "0000")
'Me.Combo_Month.Value = Format(Month(Now()), "00")
'Me.Combo_Day.Value = Format(Day(Now()), "00")
Me.Spin_Hour.Value = 12
Me.Combo_Minute.Value = 0  ' Switched the minute spinner to a combobox as the client wanted to just pick half hours (00/30) instead of minutes

UpdatePreview  ' Updates date and time preview, works fine.
End Sub

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Private Sub Combo_Year_Change()  ' Combo_Month_Change has an equivalent sub that essentially mirrors this one
Dim wsLU As Worksheet, wbV As Workbook
Set wbV = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsLU = wbV.Worksheets("General Lookups")

Dim iMonthNo As Integer, iYearNo As Long, iMaxDate As Integer

' Set number of days based on month
iMonthNo = Me.Combo_Month.ListIndex + 1
iYearNo = Me.Combo_Year.Value
If iMonthNo = 1 Or iMonthNo = 3 Or iMonthNo = 5 Or iMonthNo = 7 Or iMonthNo = 8 Or iMonthNo = 10 Or iMonthNo = 12 Then
    Me.Combo_Day.List = wsLU.Range("Date_Days31").Value
    iMaxDate = 31
ElseIf iMonthNo = 4 Or iMonthNo = 6 Or iMonthNo = 9 Or iMonthNo = 11 Then
    Me.Combo_Day.List = wsLU.Range("Date_Days30").Value
    iMaxDate = 30
ElseIf iMonthNo = 2 Then
    Me.Combo_Day.List = wsLU.Range("Date_Days28").Value
    iMaxDate = 28
    ' Leap year div by 4
        If iYearNo / 4 = Int(iYearNo / 4) And Not (iYearNo / 100 = Int(iYearNo / 100)) Then Me.Combo_Day.List = wsLU.Range("Date_Days29").Value
        If iYearNo / 4 = Int(iYearNo / 4) And Not (iYearNo / 100 = Int(iYearNo / 100)) Then iMaxDate = 29
    ' Leap year div by 400
        If iYearNo / 4 = Int(iYearNo / 4) And iYearNo / 400 = Int(iYearNo / 400) Then Me.Combo_Day.List = wsLU.Range("Date_Days29").Value
        If iYearNo / 4 = Int(iYearNo / 4) And iYearNo / 400 = Int(iYearNo / 400) Then iMaxDate = 29
End If

' Code to attempt to change the date down if Month is switched to one with fewer days. It doesn't work.
If Me.Combo_Day.Value > iMaxDate And iMonthNo > 0 And Not Me.Combo_Day.Value = "" Then Me.Combo_Day.Value = iMaxDate

UpdatePreview  ' Updates date and time preview, works fine.
End Sub
```

**THINGS WOT HAVEN'T WORKED:**

- Adding Microsoft's own date picker (not available in Excel 2013)
- Installing the supplemental date picker as suggested by Microsoft (can't assume it'll be available on users' computers)
- Attempts to directly set the comboboxes' `.Text` or `.Value` properties through VBA, regardless of data type used.
- Attempts with dates directly (`=Month(Now())`), through variables (`=sNowMonth`), or by list index (`Me.Combo_Month.Text=Me.Combo_Month.List(Month(Now())-1)`).

I've been hunting around for a solution for this since last week. Every possibility I've found has been for older versions of Office. Can anyone help?

Comment: Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly, then you could make a date variable and then convert that to a text string:

```
Dim txtNowYear As String
Dim txtNowMonth As String
Dim txtNowDay As String

txtNowYear = Year(Now())
txtNowMonth = Month(Now())
txtNowDay = Day(Now())

Me.Combo_Year.Text = txtNowYear
Me.Combo_Month.Text = txtNowMonth
Me.Combo_Day.Text = txtNowDay
```

But depending on what you intend to use it for, it might be smarter to just change the input format to .Date

Go to Tools, Additional Control, select Microsoft Monthview Control 6.0 (SP6) And insert a date-picker in your form.

PS: A similar approach should be able to handle your second issue.

Comment: Ooooh, of course - Year() is outputting a date, so the date 2012 won't match the *value* 2012.

Comment: The Monthview control and its ilk don't exist in Excel 2013, unfortunately. It's most irksome. I can't even use the add-on date picker, since this workbook is intended to be distributed to people who can't be relied on to have it installed. :-(

Comment: Still isn't working, I'm afraid. I've tried using variables as `String`, `Integer`, and `Date`, and I've tried writing them (in various forms) to both `.Text` and `.Value`, and I keep getting *"Could not set the (Text/Value) property. Invalid property value."* I'm flummoxed. :-(

Comment: Have you set a control source on the comboboxs? You could also try changing the data type of year, date and day stings to Long, Single or Double to match the data type of your comboboxes, if

Comment: .... But if you have a control source and matchRequired is True, then you might be better off matching the date in the sheet and linking that cell as the default value - then at least you're certain you have the right format and an exact match to a value in the list.... PS: Is your drop-down working properly?

Comment: I've tried to recreate the error without luck, so I would need some more details to help. could you post the entire code of the form (initialize and change codes if relevant - I assume days are dependent on month and year). What er the properties of the comboboxes?... And maybe: What's the whole purpose? It sounds like a very complicated way to get to a simple date selection... and even if you insiste on going down this road, making the named range "Days_Dates31" dependent on the year and month comboboxes (or their controlsource) would keep you from a Feb 31st scenario.

Comment: Yeah, it surprises me that such a simple and common thing as inputting a date becomes so difficult in Excel. Removing the built-in date picker in Excel 2013 was a very weird decision. I don't have control sources set - I looked them up briefly the other day, but not in any detail. And yes, the day numbers depend on month and year, but they're not changed down if you switch to February later. Anyway, I'll add the full code to the question.

Comment: I've tried using list indices too, but still no luck. The stumbling block seems to be trying to set .Text or .Value from outside the combobox itself.

Comment: Why would you set the values from outside the combobox? If you want the current date as the default value when the form is initialized (which should work with the above code - it does for me anyway), then all changes would be made in the combobox, right? If you are struggling with the date issue (e.g. Feb 31st), then I suggest clearing combo_Day if combo_Month is changed (and create an error) in order to force a valid entry. Also, I think your Combo_Year_Change is very heavy and some of it should be moved to combo_month_Change... but a dynamic named range to fix your date concern is better.

Comment: Yeah, I moved some things around and broke the update process out into its own sub. I'd rather avoid helper ranges to minimise the amount of extra bits cluttering up the sheets. Anyway, I broke the combobox value question into a shorter, more specific question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37546592/setting-value-of-a-userform-combobox/37546902) and got an answer that worked nicely. Your advice on using a date variable instead of getting values directly also proved very useful and solved a lot of problems for me - thanks!