# Setting value of a UserForm Combobox

Tags: excel, combobox, excel-2013, userform, vba

(Narrowed down from my broader question at [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37457314/setting-combobox-values-on-initialisation-and-change-of-other-comboboxes) as advised [in meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324117/posting-improved-version-of-ones-own-question).)

I have a userform. On that userform are several comboboxes for selection year, month and day. The day combobox is populated with numbers up to 28, 29, 30 or 31 depending on what year and month is selected. To avoid selecting things like the 31st of February, I'd like to check if the selected day value exceeds the maximum for that month, and reduce it appropriately. At the moment I've tried these options:

```
If Me.Combo_Day.Value > iMaxDate And iMonthNo > 0 And Not Me.Combo_Day.Value = "" Then Me.Combo_Day.Value = Me.Combo_Day.List(iMaxDate - 1)
```

and

```
If Me.Combo_Day.Value > iMaxDate And iMonthNo > 0 And Not Me.Combo_Day.Value = "" Then Me.Combo_Day.Value = iMaxDate
```

Neither of them work; any time that line gets parsed, I get a 380 error with the explanation "Could not set the Value property. Invalid property value."

I've tried changing both `.Text` and `.Value`, and neither seem to make much difference. **How do I change the selected value in a combobox?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit due to a misunderstanding of reqs:

My fault, I misunderstood the original post. If the days are set in numerical order, you can indeed use the `ListIndex` (just remember it starts with zero, so you'll have to subtract 1). It would look like:

`Me.Combo_Day.ListIndex = (iMaxDate - 1)`

Does that work?

Comment: Thanks - but, the check works fine. It's not combined into a date at this stage, so it just checks the `.Value` of the Day combobox against the maximum given for that month. The problem arises when I try to *set* the combobox's selected value to the highest available in that month. I had high hopes that I could use a list index, but to no avail. Any thoughts?

Comment: @AndrewPerry My fault, I misunderstood the original post. If the days are set in numerical order, you can indeed use the `ListIndex` (just remember it starts with zero, so you'll have to subtract 1). It would look like: `Me.Combo_Day.ListIndex = (iMaxDate - 1)`  Does that work?

Comment: Aaah, the example I was copying from used `Me.Combo_Day.Value=Me.Combo_Day.ListIndex(iMaxDate-1)`. No wonder it didn't work! Many thanks, I'll try that when I get in to the office tomorrow.

Comment: Works perfectly! If you could edit it into your answer I'll get it ticked. Thanks!